# jquery Pop up box on page load & auto close after timeout

Tags: jquery, popup, social-networking

Hi i want a pop up and disable all page(on which the pop up is) and show facebook fanpage like button or social share buttons and make it compulsory like/share to every visitor or else he need to wait for some 15-20 secs to view main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following. See what I did and implement it.
the setInterval will run every 15 seconds, but the to do list in the interval is wrapped with a if statement, so it will only apply it once.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='path/to/jquery.js'></script>
<style>
#popup {
 add you styling
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id='popup'>popup content</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#popup').fadeIn();

var repeatPopUp = 0;

setInterval(function(){

if(repeatPopUp < 1){
$('#popup').hide();

repeatPopUp++;
}

}, 15000);


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```